# LaTex: Large gap in Tabular 'longtable' between content and 'subsubheading'

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, longtable

[image: snip of gap]

I'm working on my CV and I have a spacing issues when I use `longtable`. I noticed that using `\justifying` instead of `\justify` give better spacing between the body and a header, however this does not seem to work with `longtable`. I did find another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40730/vspace-before-itemize-in-a-table-cell-tabular-vs-longtable) regarding this problem, however their answer did solve my problem. Maybe did I do it wrong or is this not even that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10.5pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%tabular
\usepackage{longtable}
\ProvidesPackage{longtable}
          [2004/02/01 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC) + strut fix]
%reverse row count
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{refcount}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fakelabel}[1]{%
  \protected@xdef\@currentlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}[2]{>{\raggedleft\refstepcounter{rowcount}\fakelabel{\therowcount}\makebox[3em][r]{\color{black}\the\numexpr\getrefnumber{#1}+1 - \value{rowcount}.)}\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#2}}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Compendium}
{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}%
\begin{longtable}{ N{compendium}{1cm} L{15.5cm}}
& \justifying Etch Protocols for UW-Stout’s Plasma Reactor, Original Research, UW-Stout, Menomonie, WI. Advances in printed circuit board technology reduce footprint and increase computing power. A greater number of electrical connections between more layers of printed circuit board (PCB) creates complexity, particularly during plasma etching for circuits with high aspect ratios. This research has determined the effects of radio frequency, reactant ratios, and temperature on the etching of pre-impregnated epoxy resins using UW Stout's plasma reactors. Engineering concept design was incorporated to retrofit the plasma reactor to allow for three gases over two. Advanced Physics Capstone. Advisor: Dr. Marlann Patterson. Research, June 2016 – May 2017.
\tabularnewline
& \justifying Electro-Optical Composite Synthesis for Volume Holography, Assigned Research, UW-Stout, Menomonie, WI. Process improvement (development) of a nanostructure material capable of being synthesized utilizing at UW-Stout. Synthesis of the photorefractive polymer 2,5-dimethyl-4-(p-nitrophenylazo) benzyl ether required a revise synthesis and stoichiometric analysis to derive starting materials and quotients. The purpose of this project was for the student to dive into an unfamiliar concept and bring it as far as the semester allowed. Advisor: Dr. Marlann Patterson. Project, Spring 2017.
%\caption{Academics Table} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}
\ref{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\label{compendium}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use for example `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` after `\subsubsection*{Compendium}`. Just a dirty hack ...

Comment: Hack received and applied. Thank you! That little bit makes all the difference in the appearance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems.

- For example the `10.5pt` in line `\documentclass[a4paper,10.5pt]{article}` is not used. You can use `10pt`, `11pt` or `12pt` ...
- The current version of `longtable` is `longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)` so you need not your lines

  ```
  \ProvidesPackage{longtable}
    %[2004/02/01 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC) + strut fix]
  ```

  in your code. BTW the line is wrong in your preamble. Just delete it.
- I used package `showframe` to visualize the typing area and margins.
- I changed the length of the second column in your table like:

  ```
  \begin{longtable}{ N{compendium}{1cm} L{10.5cm}} % L{15.5cm} <==========
  ```
- To get a smalller distance between the text of command `\subsubsection*{Compendium}` and the longtable you can use command `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` like:

  ```
  \subsubsection*{Compendium}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip} % <=============================================
  ```

With the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[%
  a4paper,
% 10.5pt % <============================================================
]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe} % <==============================================

%tabular
\usepackage{longtable}
%\ProvidesPackage{longtable}
          %[2004/02/01 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC) + strut fix]
%reverse row count
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fakelabel}[1]{%
  \protected@xdef\@currentlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}[2]{>{\raggedleft\refstepcounter{rowcount}\fakelabel{\therowcount}\makebox[3em][r]{\color{black}\the\numexpr\getrefnumber{#1}+1 - \value{rowcount}.)}\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#2}}


\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Compendium}
\vspace{-\baselineskip} % <=============================================
{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}%
\begin{longtable}{ N{compendium}{1cm} L{10.5cm}} % L{15.5cm} <==========
& \justifying Etch Protocols for UW-Stout’s Plasma Reactor, Original 
  Research, UW-Stout, Menomonie, WI. Advances in printed circuit board 
  technology reduce footprint and increase computing power. A greater 
  number of electrical connections between more layers of printed 
  circuit board (PCB) creates complexity, particularly during plasma 
  etching for circuits with high aspect ratios. This research has 
  determined the effects of radio frequency, reactant ratios, and 
  temperature on the etching of pre-impregnated epoxy resins using UW 
  Stout's plasma reactors. Engineering concept design was incorporated 
  to retrofit the plasma reactor to allow for three gases over two. 
  Advanced Physics Capstone. Advisor: Dr. Marlann Patterson. Research, 
  June 2016 -– May 2017.
\tabularnewline
& \justifying Electro-Optical Composite Synthesis for Volume Holography, Assigned Research, UW-Stout, Menomonie, WI. Process improvement (development) of a nanostructure material capable of being synthesized utilizing at UW-Stout. Synthesis of the photorefractive polymer 2,5-dimethyl-4-(p-nitrophenylazo) benzyl ether required a revise synthesis and stoichiometric analysis to derive starting materials and quotients. The purpose of this project was for the student to dive into an unfamiliar concept and bring it as far as the semester allowed. Advisor: Dr. Marlann Patterson. Project, Spring 2017.
%\caption{Academics Table} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}
text \ref{tab:myfirstlongtable} text
\label{compendium}%
}
text \ref{tab:myfirstlongtable} text
text \ref{compendium} text

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I realize my code is not so great but my professor insists on me learning this better, so I am. I'm a chemist not a physicists, and my HTML is 20 years old now (truly BBEdit was a god when I created web site), so my coding is more like cooking spaghetti -- throw it at something as see if it sticks. Your help is really appreciated. I wouldn't have ever tried to test the code like you did. Something to write a note about for sure! And I did test the fortsize and it didn't look like 0.5 did anything, but it didn't error out and it fit in my margins...Thank you again!!

Comment: @MatthewOlson You are welcome! (BTW:10.5pt throws a warning: global value 10.5pt not used. It is always a good idea to check the `*.log` file for errors and warnings ;-)