# Issue with itemize inside a tabular

Tags: tables, itemize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enumerate/itemize without margins in table cell best practice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32425/enumerate-itemize-without-margins-in-table-cell-best-practice)

I'm new to LaTeX. I'm trying to create `a tabular` and I'm facing the following small issue.

I have one `itemize` structure in one of the cells. I am using it like this: `\item[Title:] description`. I would have expected "title:" to be in bold, but it's not. Is it because it's inside a tabular?

Also, it takes out a small space over and beneath it, so that another cell's content on the left or right side isn't aligned anymore. Can I remove that extra space?

Here is what I believe an example of my issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}{a&
\begin{itemize}
\item[Title1:] Description 1
\item[Title2:] Description 2
\end{itemize}
}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

So in that case, "a" and "title1: Description 1" aren't aligned, and "title1" and "title2" aren't in bold.

Comment: You should consult the manual of `tabularx`. There are many examples on this site.

Comment: Why would tabularx solve the itemize issue ?

Comment: It would help to see what you have tried so far. That way we can answer much faster by copying your code into our text editors and go from there without having to think about how _you_'ve solved the problem so far. Would you mind helping us (helping you) by editing your question and adding the code (including everything necessary such as `\begin{document}` but as few lines as necessary)?

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. Done.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). (I have done that for you. )

Comment: The enumitem package doesn't seem to have a inline option in my case. If I remove it, it says enumerate* does not exist. If I change it to enumerate, it also produces an error. In the end, just removing the \usepackage{enumitem} allowed to come back to a error free compilation, but the problem is still not solved.

Comment: you're missing an `\end{itemize}`... was that intentional?

Comment: not only you are missing `\end{itemize}` but you are also missing `\end{tabular}`. these environments follow the syntax `\begin{env}...\end{env}` NOT `\begin{env}{...}` as you seem to be using (at least in your MWE.

Comment: Itemize doesn't do any bolding outside a table either. You should use a `description` list to get that effect.

Comment: Sorry about the missing end{env}. I corrected it. This was just a code snippet to show you my problem, but in my code it compiles without error, yet the output is not what I expect, because, as I said, the option in the itemize ("title1" and "title2") isn't in bold, and the cell with the itemize takes a lot of white spaces beneath and over it, so much so that the text isn't aligned with the other cells ("a", in the snippet example).

Comment: I also added a comment on the other question this one links to, since this one is closed...

Comment: @jlo17: As I said, `itemize` never does that, so that is an entirely separate issue.