# Text aligning like numbers aligning

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to align such that

```
Some_Text  1. Other Text       
           2. Other Text
```

I used

```
\begin{align*}
\text{Some_Text}&\text{Other Text}\\
&\text{Other Text}\\
\end{align*}
```

But it did not work.

Here is my Preamble:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=500mm,paperheight=50]{geometry}
```

Comment: If you are not using `beamer`, [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package offers a lot of customization options for such lists

Comment: "But it did not work.": The problem with this one is the `_`. You must escape it by `\_`. :)

But having said that, I am not sure this is the right way to achieve what you're trying to do. I'll write an answer... :)

Comment: While you _can_ use `align` to align text elements, `align` is really intended for equation alignments so best to use `tabular` or `enumerate` type of environment. If this is something you do often you may want to consider defining a custom environment for this.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my first try, I am not great with tables, but I would like to try:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{\linewidth}}
Some\_Text  & \vspace{-1em}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Other text
  \item Other text
\end{enumerate}
\end{tabular}
More text.
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Here is another possibility (to get over the trick of inserting negative `\vspace`. This answer is taken from Marco's answer, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32429/10679), using `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{\linewidth}}
Some\_Text&
\begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
\item foo
\item bar
\end{enumerate*}
\end{tabular}
More text.
\end{document}
```

Thanks to David for helping me with this one in the chat room.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But, I am using documentclass book to use geometry to resize the page size. The page size is very abnormal. Something like 1:10. So, your first code works with amsart document class but not book documentclass. Thanks anyway. If you have solution to this, it would be great.

Comment: @700resu Could you please post your preamble? So, that, I can see how I'd tweak this solution...

Comment: nothing more only: 
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=500mm,paperheight=50]{geometry}. Thanks.

Comment: don't ask me what I am doing with 500*50 mm page. :)

Comment: @700resu That would be none of my business. :)

Comment: @700resu The second of the solution still works! As for the first, someone with more expertise only can help. I am out of depth now.

Answer (score 4):

With a fixed-width column containing the enumeration, the following is a possibility:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myitem}{\par\refstepcounter{enumi}\theenumi.\ }
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rp{0.5\linewidth}}
  Some\textunderscore text &
    \myitem Other text
    \myitem Other text
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If you wish to have a different kind of enumeration display, adjust `\myitem` to your liking. For example,

```
\newcommand{\myitem}{\par\refstepcounter{enumi}(\theenumi)\ }
```

provides brakcets around the numbering. The width of the second column is still an issue (whether it's sufficient or bad, say), but there's not much more one can do with the amount of detail available in the question.